# How do I solve this error? "Invalid requirement: '<!DOCTYPE html>' "

Tags: terminal, ocr

I am trying to install [this](https://github.com/stafazzoli/FarsiOCR). I am getting the following error when I try to install the requirements via OSX terminal:

```
Invalid requirement: '<!DOCTYPE html>' (from line 8 of requirements.txt)
```

I do not understand how to solve this error.

The requirements are below. `Pytesseract==0.3.9` is line 8.

```
docx2txt==0.8
numpy==1.22.3
opencv-python==4.5.5.64
packaging==21.3
pdf2image==1.16.0
Pillow==9.3.0
pyparsing==3.0.7
pytesseract==0.3.9
python-Levenshtein==0.12.2
```